# do while loop in SAS macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

folks.

here is my code:

```
%macro loop;
%let var1=10;
%do %while (&var1.>x);
    counter=&var1.;
    yy=1/(1+x);
    end;
    %let var1=%eval(&var1.-1);
%end;
%mend loop;
data tmp;
    input x;
datalines;
1
2
3
;
run;
%let num=1;
data y;
set tmp;
%loop;
run;
```

basically, I want to create a variable yy when the variable x less than the value of var1;

But the output didn't give me variable yy.

Can any one help me with this?

Thx!

Comment: Why are you using macro code?

Comment: good question! because I have to, it's a simple part of a very big project, I got to achieve this without changing other parts.

Comment: First figure out what code you need to run. Then figure out how to generate that code using macro variables or macro logic.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing `%do` and `do`.

`%do` is if you want to repeat a section of code over and over again, as if you'd typed it a bunch of times.  The arguments for continuing/ending a `%do` loop must be known before the dataset is opened - they must be text, or they must be the text contained in a macro variable (not the data in one).

`do` is if you want to iterate over a data step variable.  The arguments for continuing/ending a `do` loop can be data from the data set, or can be text, or can be the value from a dataset variable or text stored in a macro variable.

So, you want:

```
%let var1=C;
data want;
    x= 3;
    counter=0;
    do &var1. = 10 to 1 by -1 while ( &var1. > x);
      yy = 1/(1+x);
      counter=counter+1;
    end;

run;
```

I'm not sure why you're looping here, though.  You can determine this answer without any loop.

Comment: Does the do while loop make sense here? Since the variables aren't involved in calculation the end of the loop is fixed?

Comment: That's what I mean by my last paragraph... I don't understand why this is a loop.  I illustrate it properly to show the difference from the macro loop, but yes, why this is a loop escapes me.